# Resize and upload picture via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code that resize the image and I want it to upload after resizing photo and submit the form using Ajax. I tried doing it but, it doesn't seems to resize my photo. I'm new to Javascript, please guide me. Below is my code:-

```
    <form id="imgLocal" name="imgLocal" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="receipt" id="receipt" accept="images/*" onchange="handleFiles();" />
    </form>

    // Form validation above

    submitHandler:function(form) {
    var formData = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'a/imgUpload',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
                }).success(function(data){
                    show('loading', false);
                    alert('success');
                }else {
                   alert('error');
}

        function handleFiles()
        {
            var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('receipt').files;
            var file = filesToUpload[0];

            // Create an image
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            // Create a file reader
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Set the image once loaded into file reader
            reader.onload = function(e)
            {
                img.src = e.target.result;

                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
                var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;

                if (width > height) {
                  if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                  }
                } else {
                  if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                  }
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                  $('#receipt').attr('value', dataurl); 
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should make fiddle for this.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi

Validation & Ajax works fine, just that the image I send using ajax is not what I want, it gets the original picture instead of the modified picture.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I beleive you cannot change the value of the file inpur yourself for security reasons. You need to add the changed file to the FileList Manually instead of trying to change the input Elements Value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set a file input with new data, the user has to choose a file for security reasons.

In order to upload a generated image you can upload the data url and decode the base64 string back to binary format and save it server side. Or you can get the image from the canvas as a blob and then attach it to your FormData object.

instead of calling `toDataURL` you can call [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) to get a blob object.

```
canvas.toBlob(function(imgBlob){
   formData.append("receipt",imgBlob,"filenameForImage.png");
},'image/png');
```

Note that the `toBlob` method is not yet fully supported, but the MDN reference does give a polyfill that can be used:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob
>
> ```
> if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
>  Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, toBlob, {
>   value: function (callback, type, quality) {
>
>     var binStr = atob( this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
>         len = binStr.length,
>         arr = new Uint8Array(len);
>
>     for (var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
>      arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
>     }
>
>     callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );
>   }
>  });
> }
> ```

Comment: Any other solution that doesn't touch the server side related?

Comment: @MuthaFury, The example i gave doesnt do anything on the server side. I only mentioned sending the data url and decoding on the server side as an example that sending the blob was not the only way to upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**html**

```
<form id="imgLocal" name="imgLocal" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="receipt" id="receipt" accept="images/*" onchange="handleFiles();" />
</form>

<script>  

    function handleFiles()
    {

        var image= document.getElementById('receipt');

        var file = image.files[0];
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                    img.onload = function () {
                            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                            var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
                            var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
                            var width = this.width;
                            var height = this.height;
                            if (width > height) {
                                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                                            width = MAX_WIDTH;
                                    }
                            } else {
                                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                                            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                                    }
                            }
                            canvas.width = width;
                            canvas.height = height;
                            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                            var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                            upload(dataurl);
                    };
                    image.onerror= function() {
                            alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
                    };
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}

function upload(file) {
                var form = new FormData();
                form.append('image', file);      
                $.ajax({
                      url: 'server.php',
                      data: form,
                      processData: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                      }
                 });
     }

</script>
```

Server side :

```
<?php

$filename = "image_".uniqid().".png";
$dest = __DIR__.$filename;

$imgData = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['image']);
$imgData =  substr($imgData,strpos($imgData,",")+1);
$imgData = base64_decode($imgData);

$file = fopen($dest, 'w');
fwrite($file, $imgData);
fclose($file);

?>
```

[Check my blog](http://ijasnahamed.blogspot.in/2015/05/re-size-captures-image-from-web-before.html)

Comment: This does resize the image dimensions, but it creates a much bigger image in size when I made it smaller in dimensions (a 16KB image turned into a 220KB image). Any ideas to overcome that?